# inset session id and segment

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, insert

I am trying to get segment (3) and insert it into my new table with my session ID but im stuck .. any idea

**Model**

```
    function old_report_create()
        {
$reportID = $this->input->post('ReportID');
            $userID_staff = $this->session->userdata('StaffID');
            if (isset($reportID) && isset($userID)) {
                $new_read = array(
                    'ReportID' => $reportID,
                    'StaffID' => $userID_staff,
                );
                return $this->db->insert('Read_Report', $new_read);
            }
            return FALSE;
        }
```

**View**

```
<?= form_open('main/add_old_report'); ?>
        <?= form_hidden('ReportID', $this->uri->segment(3)); ?>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Read Report"/></p>
        </form>
```

**Controller**

```
function add_old_report()
    {
        if ($query = $this->report_model->old_report_create()) {

            $this->session->set_flashdata('messagetwo', 'You marked report as read');
            redirect('main/comments/' . $_POST['ReportID']);

        } else {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('messagetwo', 'Sorry not this time');
            redirect('main/comments/' . $_POST['ReportID']);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the issue and what is your request url while loading the view?

Comment: The problem is its not inserting the data, and how do you mean request url. im trying to request the third segment of the url that should be a number, then i want to insert that number

Comment: I means that when your view is loaded then what is http url in browser address?

Comment: main/comments/53 so the third segment is 53, however its not getting it

Comment: Did you able to see the value in form hidden field via Inspect Element tool?

Comment: hmmm good point 1 min...UPDATE yes i can

Comment: Are you able to insert record into the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to update your model function with this:

**Model Function:**

```
function old_report_create()
{
    $reportID = $this->input->post('ReportID');
    $userID = $this->session->userdata('StaffID');
    if (isset($reportID) && isset($userID)) {
        $new_read = array(
            'ReportID' => $reportID,
            'StaffID' => $userID,
        );
        $this->db->insert('Read_Report', $new_read);
        return $this->db->insert_id();
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

*Hope this will help to solve your issue !!*

Comment: @Beep, Update your model function with this one

Comment: I just worked it out myself 5 mins ago, but this is correct ( a bit neater than mine) thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe field types are wrong. Because, codeigniter adds quotes near of values. So Mysql reads them as String, not like expected type?

```
$new_read = array(
       'ReportID' => (int)$reportID,
       'StaffID' => $userID_staff
   );
```